# Long tables in emacs org do not export correctly through latex-pdf

Tags: latex, org-table, org-mode

I want to export two long tables (each 6X179). I tried to export with latex-->PDF using `#+ATTR_LATEX: :float sidewaystable` attribute. But what I get is this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dgEW.png), I get just three pages pdf file (tables are cut at the first page).

Comment: Can you please update your example with your emacs and org versions and a minimum working example of an org file which doesn't export as your intend?

Comment: Org 8.3.5. Emacs 24-5-1 (OSX). [code](http://ix.io/1643)

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason the answer proposed by Kaushal is not working on my system (Org version ?). Anyway I find out a working solution using the `pandoc` export instead of the Org *native* LaTeX. So using the same [example](http://ix.io/16lG) and exporting to Pandoc-->Latex and Open you get a tex [file](http://ix.io/16ED) with `longtable` package. I made a slight modification adding the `lscape`package. This is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, **but** .. it seems like `minted` and `float` packages do not work well with `sidewaystable` environment. So this looks like more of a question for https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

When you do `C-c C-e l o` on the below, pdf generation will fail.

**You will need to hack the `.tex` file and comment out the `\usepackage` lines for `minted` and `float` if present.**

Then the tex to pdf conversion will happen fine on doing

```
\latexmk -xelatex -quiet -shell-escape *.tex
```

---

The `sidewaystable` value in `#+ATTR_LATEX:`, while still works, is deprecated since Org 8.3. `sideways` should be used instead.

---

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

#+CAPTION: foo
#+NAME: tab__foo
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float sideways
| Data  | Numero Progr. | Descrizione o Fornitore | Importi delle operazioni |           Importi Imponibili |               Iva |
|-------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------|
| 07/01 |           313 | ACLS Corso              |                   317.20 |                       260.00 |              57.2 |
| 07/01 |           314 | Libro Amazon            |                    76.59 |                        62.78 |             13.81 |
| 17/01 |           315 | Bottega della Pizza     |                      8.8 |                         7.21 |              1.59 |
| 23/01 |           316 | Pizzeria Passaparola    |                    11.00 |                         9.02 |              1.98 |
```

---

[image]

---

Versions:

- GNU Emacs 25.1.50.7 of 2016-07-20 built using commit 852111f3a6640d61ea1a1b2fd0cbf50623642927 (master branch).
- Org-mode version 8.3.4 (release_8.3.4-1049-g481709) (master branch, so actually Org 9.x)

Comment: I tried with your hack but still I got the same problem. This is my generated [tex](http://ix.io/16g0) file

Comment: If you look carefully at my answer above, that hack is not the only thing required. Notice that the **CAPTION**, **NAME** (not LABEL) and **ATTR_LATEX** (with **sideways**, not sidewaystable) are directly above the org table that you want to format in a `sidewaystable` environment. That is required for each table. Also, in newer org versions, you cannot use the colon `:` character in the NAME field. So I have used `tab__` instead of `tab:`. Can you check if my example above works for you directly?

Comment: Using your [example](http://ix.io/16lG) produce the same [result](http://i.imgur.com/RBTSpZ7.png)